# merge columns sidewise SAS

Tags: sas

I am trying to merge the columns sideways which is resulting in many to many as the BY values have Duplicates.

Source:

```
ID A1 A2 A3
1  x1
1  x2
1     x3
1  x4
1        x5
1        x6
```

want:

```
ID A1 A2 A3
1  x1 x3 x5
1  x2    x6
1  x4
```

I seperated the columns into 3 different datasets, and used a merge statement with BY ID however this doesnot give me the desired output dataset.

Comment: You did not show the code you tried.  That would help.  The sample data indicates a column does not have any value runs with a gap between.  What happens if A1 in row 6 is X7 ? Or does that never happen ?

Comment: Please confirm my edit of your question and add the code to separate the columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The merge can be facilitated by adding an additional key item during preprocessing (the column splitting).

This example presumes the merge is of only non-missing values.

```
data have;
input ID A1-A3;
format _numeric_ 2.;
datalines;
1  1  .  .
1  2  .  .
1  3  .  .
1  .  4  .
1  .  .  5
1  .  .  6
;
```

A macro is useful for generating the views that will be merged.  The variable `seq` becomes all important later during the `merge` as a synthetic key item in the `by` statement.

```
* for use with data set named have;
%macro make_view_no_missings (column=);
  data &column / view=&column;
    set have; 
    by id; 
    if first.id then seq = 0;
    if not missing (&column);  * use if instead of where (to ensure original row ordering);
    seq + 1;
    keep id seq &column; 
  run;
%mend;
```

Use the macro to create views of the column stripes.

```
options mprint;

%make_view_no_missings (column=a1);
%make_view_no_missings (column=a2);
%make_view_no_missings (column=a3);
```

Merge the stripes using the original key (`id`) plus `seq`

```
data want;
  merge a1-a3;
  by id seq;
  drop seq;
run;
```

A more complex preprocess would be needed to handle a requirement of stripping a groups column of leading and trailing runs of missing values, while keeping internals runs of missings.

Answer (score 3):

So it looks like you want to take advantage of how SAS does many-to-many merges so that you can pair the first non-missing value of A2 with with first non-missing value of A3, etc.

But you need to add in code to prevent the normal retaining of the last value for the shorter lists. This happens because SAS does not read anything from the datasets that are shorter and so the value read from the last observation is retained.

Use the `OUTPUT` statement to write the observation and then use `CALL MISSING()` to empty the column variables.  Then on the next iteration the input datasets that are still providing observations will be read.

```
data want ;
  merge have (keep=id a1 where=(not missing(a1)))
        have (keep=id a2 where=(not missing(a2)))
        have (keep=id a3 where=(not missing(a3)))
  ;
  by id;
  output;
  call missing(of A1-A3);
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

## You should be merging by unique key

If you only merge on ID, SAS assumes a **one-to-many** relationship.
To enforce SAS tot associate one observation with one observation, you should add a variable to the `by`statement to get a unique key.

```
data target;
    merge Source1 Source2 Source3;
    by ID case;
    drop case;
run;
```

## This extra variable could for instance be a simple counter

```
data Source1 / view=Source1;
    set Source;
    where not missing (A1);
    case = _N_;
    keep ID A1 case;
run;
data Source2 / view=Source2;
    set Source;
    where not missing (A2);
    case = _N_;
    keep ID A2 case;
run;
data Source3 / view=Source3;
    set Source;
    where not missing (A3);
    case = _N_;
    keep ID A3 case;
run;
```

To fully understand why this works, you should know `_N_` is an automatic variable, set to the observation number. It is assigned after the application of the `where` statement. (_Note that you cannot use an if statement here, as this is only applied after the assignment of the observation number to *N*.)_

## I created the source with

```
data source;
    input 
        @1 ID 2.
        @4 A1 $2.
        @7 A2 $2.
        @10 A3 $2.;
datalines;
1  x1
1  x2
1     x3
1  x4
1        x5
1        x6
;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

This code creates a row based on column number and merges on that. We drop it off on the final table. Should be straight forward. Let me know if you have any questions.

```
data ds1;
   length A1 $ 2;
   input ID A1 $;
    n = _N_;
   datalines;
1 x1
1 x2
1 x4
;
data ds2;
   length A2 $ 2;
   input ID A2 $;
    n = _N_;
   datalines;
1 x3
;
data ds3;
   length A3 $ 2;
   input ID A3 $;
    n = _N_;
   datalines;
1 x5
1 x6
;

data Final;
    merge ds1 ds2 ds3;
    by n;
    keep ID A1 A2 A3;
run;
```